# Adapt textarea max word plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would one adapt this jquery plugin so that it counts down from how many words your allowed/you have remaining, instead of counting up to how many your allowed.

www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/enforceform.shtml

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open the maxlength.js file and put this

```
$field.data('$statusdiv').css('color', '').html( $field.data('maxsize') - $field.val().length )
```

instead of this:

```
$field.data('$statusdiv').css('color', '').html($field.val().length)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also a very simple way to do it *without* a maxlength attribute. (This example uses 200 as the maximum characters).

```
$("#YourTextareaId").keyup(function () {
var i = $("#YourTextareaId").val().length;
$('#IdOfCountdownDisplay').val(''+200-i+'');
```

A nice thing to remember when coding, is that a simple equation can get rid of a whole lot of complicated code.